# how to remove unused php versions from ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Yesterday I tried to install php-gd for php7.2.15 on Ubuntu 18.04 lts. Today when Ubuntu got updated it installed php5.6 php7.0 php7.1 php7.3 beside my php7.2. I think I did something wrong but now I just don't want these versions on my server It's a server holding website and app so can't play with it, `php -v` now shows:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   pdo_parse_params), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   7.3.2-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 15:43:57) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.3.2-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

But phpinfo file is normal not mentioning anything irregular and everything is functioning like normal, but I'd like to keep my server clean so any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to find the `pdo_mysql.so` file manually using find
2. Edit your php.ini file so it points to the right location of this file.

Most likely php mysql library got overwritten as a result of installation of multiple versions of php. Also make sure you are editing the right php.ini file.